# How do I get wsgi to process more than one request at once?

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

I want to create a long-polling server with uWSGI. The problem is that for some reason, it will only process (or wait for) one request at a time. To demonstrate, the following sample has the same issue:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import time

def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        yield "<h1>%s</h1><br />" % i
        time.sleep(5)
```

The following also displays the same issue:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent import pywsgi
from gevent import queue
import time

def issue(body):
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        body.put("<h1>%s</h1><br />" % i)
        time.sleep(5)

def application(env, start_response):
    body = queue.Queue()
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    gevent.spawn(issue, body)
    return body
```

I start uwsgi with `sudo -u www-data uwsgi --gevent 100 --post-buffering=4096 --processes 4 --socket /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock --wsgi-file tmp.wsgi` and have tried adding `--async 100` which changes nothing.

Again, how do I get wsgi to process more than one request at once? You should be able to see two tabs in chrome counting simultaneously.

Update: it seems to only have this problem when requesting from two tabs in chrome. I suspect it is due to a browser limitation.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21774196/1914052