# How to process multiple ajax from client in cherrypy simultaneously

Tags: python, ajax, cherrypy

When I send out multiple ajax requests from the client, it seems that the requests are handled in sequential manner by cherrypy and when one requests take more time, it blocks other requests also.

Is there a way to achieve parallel processing using cherrypy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that is something related to [session locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190526/how-to-make-cherrypy-serve-concurrent-requests/28205729#28205729).

Are you using the `cherrypy.tools.sessions`?

Comment: Thansk a ,lot, it helped, I added expicit and it worked out well